Apache Beam/Dataflow performance regression potentially related to `grpcio`
I am trying to track down a performance regression, and want to confirm it's not a me problem but rather an actual problem people are seeing as well.
Basically my hypothesis is that Apache Beam pulls in a version of grpcio that's "new" by default and there has been a performance regression related to that package since 1.45.0.
I have already opened an issue ages ago but haven't had the time to revisit this until now. Link: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/22159
The symptom of this is basically the CPU usage of your beam/dataflow worker will never hit 100% consistently, it's attached in the issue I linked above.
As indicated in the GitHub issue I linked, I have tried different version of grpcio and discovered that 1.45.0 (and potentially every version since then) is the version that cause the regression. I just want to confirm this is not an isolated observation by me.

Have you tried to use the latest Beam?

Yes - seems to be seeing the same issue. Nothing definitive yet, and I haven't had the time to come up with a minimal reproducible example, but I will do soon.

Please keep updating the Beam GitHub issue. If we have a repro example, that will help the team a lot. Thanks.
